# Select highest value from python list of dicts

Tags: python, list, numpy

In a list of list of dicts:

```
 A = [
       [{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 3}, {'x': 3, 'y': 4}, {'x': 4, 'y': 7}],

       [{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}, {'x': 3, 'y': 13}, {'x': 4, 'y': 0}],

       [{'x': 1, 'y': 20}, {'x': 2, 'y': 4}, {'x': 3, 'y': 0}, {'x': 4, 'y': 8}]

     ]
```

I need to retrieve the highest 'y' values from each of the list of dicts...so the resulting list would contain:

```
 Z = [(4, 7), (3,13), (1,20)]
```

In A, the 'x' is the key of each dict while 'y' is the value of each dict.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: why did you tag this numpy? Also a tuple looks like a much faster data structure to use, you can retain dictionary clarity if you so desire by using `collections.namedtuple`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`max` accept optional `key` parameter.

```
A = [
    [{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 3}, {'x': 3, 'y': 4}, {'x': 4, 'y': 7}],
    [{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}, {'x': 3, 'y': 13}, {'x': 4, 'y': 0}],
    [{'x': 1, 'y': 20}, {'x': 2, 'y': 4}, {'x': 3, 'y': 0}, {'x': 4, 'y': 8}]
]

Z = []
for a in A:
    d = max(a, key=lambda d: d['y'])
    Z.append((d['x'], d['y']))
print Z
```

**UPDATE**

suggested by – J.F. Sebastian:

```
from operator import itemgetter
Z = [itemgetter(*'xy')(max(lst, key=itemgetter('y'))) for lst in A]
```

Comment: or as a list comprehension: `Z = [itemgetter(*'xy')(max(lst, key=itemgetter('y'))) for lst in A]`

Comment: This looks awesome. For anyone wondering `itemgetter(*'xy')` is equivalent to `itemgetter('x', 'y')` (I prefer the latter for clarity but this also looks nice)

Answer (score 5):

I'd use `itemgetter` and `max`'s `key` argument:

```
from operator import itemgetter

pair_getter = itemgetter('x', 'y')
[pair_getter(max(d, key=itemgetter('y'))) for d in A]
```

Comment: +1 Nice one! itemgetter doc:  http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter

Answer (score 4):

```
[max(((d['x'], d['y']) for d in l), key=lambda t: t[1]) for l in A]
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your stated problem has been given, but I suggest changing your underlying data structure. Tuples are much faster for small elements such as a *point*. You may retain the clarity of a dictionary by using `namedtuple` if you so desire.

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> A = [
       [{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 3}, {'x': 3, 'y': 4}, {'x': 4, 'y': 7}],

       [{'x': 1, 'y': 0}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2}, {'x': 3, 'y': 13}, {'x': 4, 'y': 0}],

       [{'x': 1, 'y': 20}, {'x': 2, 'y': 4}, {'x': 3, 'y': 0}, {'x': 4, 'y': 8}]

     ]
```

Making a `Point` namedtuple is simple

```
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
```

This is what an instance looks like

```
>>> Point(x=1, y=0) # Point(1, 0) also works
Point(x=1, y=0)
```

`A` would then look like this

```
>>> A = [[Point(**y) for y in x] for x in A]
>>> A
[[Point(x=1, y=0), Point(x=2, y=3), Point(x=3, y=4), Point(x=4, y=7)], 
 [Point(x=1, y=0), Point(x=2, y=2), Point(x=3, y=13), Point(x=4, y=0)], 
 [Point(x=1, y=20), Point(x=2, y=4), Point(x=3, y=0), Point(x=4, y=8)]]
```

Now working like this is much easier:

```
>>> from operator import attrgetter
>>> [max(row, key=attrgetter('y')) for row in A]
[Point(x=4, y=7), Point(x=3, y=13), Point(x=1, y=20)]
```

To retain the speed advantages of tuples it's better to access by index:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [max(row, key=itemgetter(2)) for row in A]
[Point(x=4, y=7), Point(x=3, y=13), Point(x=1, y=20)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result=[]
for item in a:
    new = sorted(item, key=lambda k: k['y'],reverse=True)
    result.append((new[0]['x'],new[0]['y']))
print(result)
```

Note-The is not the efficient way to do this but this is one of the ways to get the required result.